# Parameter pack expansion in a lambda with Visual Studio 2015: error C3546

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39275674/6612932), I tried to compile the following code:

```
template<typename... Types>
auto for_each(type_list<Types...>) {
    return [](auto&& f) {
        using swallow = int[];
        (void) swallow { 0, (void(f(tag<Types>{})), 0)... };
    };
}
```

This works fine with gcc, but generate the following error with visual studio 2015:

> ```
> main.cpp(19): error C3546: '...': there are no parameter packs available to expand
>
> main.cpp(48): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'auto for_each::<lambda_9a452bac795593df4639d6433fa242d3>::operator ()<main::<lambda_b7b233027d9428cb5ddc16c87ea59d21>>(main::<lambda_b7b233027d9428cb5ddc16c87ea59d21> &&) const' being compiled
>
> main.cpp(18): error C3520: 'Types': parameter pack must be expanded in this context
>
> main.cpp(18): error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found
>
> main.cpp(18): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'auto main::<lambda_b7b233027d9428cb5ddc16c87ea59d21>::operator ()(_T1) const'
>
> main.cpp(18): note: With the following template arguments:
>
> main.cpp(18): note: '_T1=tag<Types>'
> ```

Looks like visual compiler fails expansion when symbol `...` is not tied to the parameter pack(?)

Is there a way to solve the problem?

Here is a minimal example to generate the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename... > struct type_list {};

template<typename T>
struct tag { using type = T; };

template<typename... Types>
auto for_each(type_list<Types...>) {
    return [](auto&& f) {
        using swallow = int[];
        (void) swallow { 0, (void(f(tag<Types>{})), 0)... };
    };
}

struct A {
    static std::string get_type_name() { return { "A" }; }
};

struct AA : A {
    static std::string get_type_name() { return { "AA" }; }
};

int main() {
    for_each(type_list<A, AA>{}) (
        [&](auto t) {
            using B = typename decltype(t)::type;
            std::cout << B::get_type_name() << std::endl;
        }
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this code is ill formed since `auto &&f` cannot be an overloaded function, while you use it as such.

Comment: @dani huh?  I do not follow.  In the example `f` is a lambda.

Comment: Flailing about, try capturing `type_list`?

Comment: @Yakk What do you mean? Capturing `type_list` in the lambda inside the declaration of `for_each`?

Comment: @was yes.  Eother explicitly or implicitly.  Dount would work, but would be something I would try.  Another approach might be to capture a tuple of type-tags, then use a helper function object to expand it.  Or just do your task in a helper function object with explicit `<Types...>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing the `for_each` function with a structure:

```
template<typename T> struct for_each {};

template<typename... Types>
struct for_each<type_list<Types...>> {
    template<typename F>
    for_each(F f) {
        using swallow = int[];
        (void) swallow { 0, (f(tag<Types>{}), 0)... };
    }
};
```

With the slightly modified usage:

```
int main() {
    for_each<type_list<A, AA>>{
        [&](auto t) {
            using B = typename decltype(t)::type;
            std::cout << B::get_type_name() << std::endl;
        }
    };

    return 0;
}
```